# How do I install dhcp plugin for Strongswan on Ubuntu focal

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, dhcp, strongswan

I've installed `strongswan`, `libstrongswan-standard-plugins` and `libstrongswan-extra-plugins` packages and it seems that `dhcp` plugin is still not there.

How do I install it? Is my only option to build from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [`libcharon-extra-plugins` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libcharon-extra-plugins) because the plugin is technically located in `libcharon` (note that the other two packages you reference are actually called `libstrongswan-...-plugins` and not `strongswan-...-plugins` because they contain plugins that are provided by `libstrongswan`).

Also note that `libcharon-extra-plugins` ships the [`kernel-libipsec` plugin](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/plugins/kernel-libipsec.html), which you generally don't want to use. So make sure it's [disabled](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/plugins/pluginLoad.html) (via `/etc/strongswan.d/charon/kernel-libipsec.conf` if `/etc/strongswan.conf` includes that file, otherwise, directly in the latter).

Comment: Something strange is going on. I've removed `libstrongswan-extra-plugins`, tried installing the package you suggest, `apt` told me that `libcharon-extra-plugins` is already the latest version and then `strongswan` suddenly began to load `libcharon` plugins including `dhcp`. I could confirm by logs that it was not loaded before these manipulations. Thanks for helping me!